# What Talmudic disputes took place in Jerusalem?

Tags: history, talmud-gemara, yerushalayim-jerusalem

I was asked this simple question, but couldn't recall one myself.
I understand that it must include pre-R'Yochanan Ben Zakkai Tannoyim, and there are not many of them, but still.

Were there disputes mentioned in the Talmud that took place explicitly in Jerusalem?

Comment: How about _Hillel v. Bnei Betera_?

Answer (score 3):

Presumably [the argument](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Gittin.56a.4?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=en) between Rabbi Zechariah ben Avkulas and the other sages over what to do with Bar Kamtza's korban. It sounds like they were arguing right there in the Mikdash.